# How do I configure Solr search to get the best match?

Tags: solr

How do you search based on the **best match instead of filtering out** the database rows that don't have **one** of the words? Is there a generic tokenizer or filter I can use?

eg if I my search terms are:
`greek american`

Then the resultset should include all strings with `greek` **OR** `american`
If the database had the following rows:

```
german food
americans in paris
greek americans
thai food
greek food
```

Then it should return the best matches on the top even though it might not have all/some of the search terms:

```
greek americans
greek food
americans in paris
```

Comment: by default SOLR returns the best match first. Care to share with us your schema and tokenizers you defined for the search-able fileds

Answer (score 1):

This is what Solr does by default. Maybe the scorer doesn't meet your expectations, you should turn debugQuery on to better understand how scores were computed.

Given your example, you should ensure that your analyzer performs stemming so that `american` and `americans` are analyzed the same way.

One thing that may be confusing when starting working with a tool which uses TF-IDF for scoring is that it gives rare terms more chance to be well ranked. For example, if `american` was much more common in your index than `greek`, a query for `greek restaurant` would likely rank greek museums higher than american restaurants.

You can customize how scores are computed by writing your own [Similarity](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like your default operator is "AND". The following should be somewhere in your schema.xml file:

```
<!-- SolrQueryParser configuration: defaultOperator="AND|OR" -->
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>
```

If you want it to be "OR" by default, use `<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>`. Otherwise, use an explicit OR in your query:

```
?q=(greek OR american)
```

If you post the relevant parts of your schema.xml file, perhaps I can help troubleshoot some more.